# Checking if XML values are in an AS3 array

Tags: arrays, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have some XML in the below format.

```
 <user uid="0001">
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0001.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>GS1234</flightno>
</user>
<user uid="0002">
    <FirstName>Luke</FirstName>
    <LastName>Dixon</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0002.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>TD1234</flightno>
</user>
<user uid="0003">
    <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
    <LastName>Kerr</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0003.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>GS1234</flightno>
</user>
```

This is a small sample, there are a couple 100 of these.

I have used E4x filtering to filter down another set of XML data that produces an as3 array. The array contains some flight numbers (eg : [GS1234,PB7367,TD1234].

I'm wondering how I can filter my XML (as shown above) to only show the users whose 'flightno' EXISTS in the AS3 array.

I'm guessing its some sort of E4X query but I can't seem to get it right!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Don't mind me using this trick with inline XML, it's not the point.
// It's here just to make it possible to copy and paste code 
// with multiline XML sample.The actual solution is a one-liner below.
var usersXML:XML = new XML(<x><![CDATA[
<data>
<user uid="0001">
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0001.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>GS1234567</flightno>
</user>
<user uid="0002">
    <FirstName>Luke</FirstName>
    <LastName>Dixon</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0002.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>TD1234</flightno>
</user>
<user uid="0003">
    <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
    <LastName>Kerr</LastName>
    <ImagePath>images/0003.jpg</ImagePath>
    <flightno>GS1234</flightno>
</user>
</data>
]]></x>.toString());

// once again, the way I create sample departingXML 
// is not important, it's just for copying and pasting into IDE.
var departingXML:XML = new XML(<x><![CDATA[
<flights>
    <flight>
        <number>GS1234</number>
        <date>10/11/2015</date>
        <time>1440</time>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <number>TD1234</number>
        <date>10/11/2015</date>
        <time>1450</time>
    </flight>
</flights>
]]></x>.toString());


// 1. create filter array
var flightNoArray:Array = [];
departingXML.flight.number.(flightNoArray.push(toString()));

trace(flightNoArray); // GS1234,TD1234
trace(typeof(flightNoArray[0])); // string

// 2. filter users:
var list:XMLList = usersXML.user.(flightNoArray.indexOf(flightno.toString()) >= 0);

trace(list); // traces users 0002 and 0003
```

I wouldn't call it efficient or at least readable though.

```
// Note: this line is somewhat queer and I don't like it,

departingXML.flight.number.(flightNoArray.push(toString()));

// but this is the only way I can now think of to get and array 
// of strings from an XMLList nodes without a loop.
// I would advise to use a readable and simple loop instead.
```

- `usersXML.user` -- this gets you an XMLList with all nodes named "user"
- `usersXML.user.(some condition)` -- this filters the XMLList of user nodes given a condition
- `flightNoArray.indexOf(flightno.toString()) >= 0` -- and this is a filter condition
- `flightno.toString()` -- gets you a string inside flightno child
- [REFERENCE: Traversing XML structures](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e60).
- [Explanation of the search trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832327/810736) in the note above.

**UPDATE:** it turned out in comments that it was also the way the filter array was populated that was causing trouble. The code below demonstrates some more E4X.

This is how the filter list was created and what was actually happening:

```
// once again, the way I create sample departingXML 
// is just for the sake of copying and pasting, it's not related to solution.
var departingXML:XML = new XML(<x><![CDATA[
<flights>
    <flight>
        <number>GS1234</number>
        <date>10/11/2015</date>
        <time>1440</time>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <number>TD1234</number>
        <date>10/11/2015</date>
        <time>1450</time>
    </flight>
</flights>
]]></x>.toString());

// the way it was done before
var flightNoArray: Array = []; 
for each(var num: XML in departingXML.flight) { 
    flightNoArray.push(num.number);

    // WARNING! num.number is an XMLList! It s NOT a string.
    // Addressing nodes by name ALWAYS gets you an XMLList, 
    // even if there's only one node with that name
    // Hence, `flightNoArray.indexOf("string")` could not possibly work, 
    // as there are lists inside of the array, not strings.


    // We can check if this is a fact:
    trace(flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(flightNoArray[flightNoArray.length-1])); 
    // (traces XMLList)

    // Or this way (note toXMLString() method)
    trace(flightNoArray[flightNoArray.length-1].toXMLString()); 
    // (traces <number>GS1234</number>)
} 

trace(flightNoArray);
```

`trace(flightNoArray);` traces GS1234,TD1234 because this is the way toString() method works for xml nodes -- it gets you text, that is inside. This is why there is a special method toXMLString(), that gets you a string representation of a node.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working that, i just get "unable to parse XML"

Comment: I guess it's just that flash pro cs6 (I'm using) is capable of parsing inline xml with multiple lines, and previous versions of flash IDE are not. Anyway, the gist is in the line below `// solution:`.

Comment: I'm using cc mate, ill have a play around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GazSmith Ok, I've updated the answer. Now it should be Ok to just copy and paste the thing.

Comment: I'm not using raw XML i get it all from an xml file online as there is around 700 users

Comment: For example my "flightNoArray is GS1234,TD1234 and userXML is 

<UserImagePaths>
 <User>
  <FirstName>Christopher</FirstName>
  <LastName>Molina</LastName>
  <ImagePath>EB29E5E5-5F5F-62FD-5C4F-27DB06388A79</ImagePath>
  <flightno>Sed</flightno>
 </User>
 <User>
  <FirstName>Lane</FirstName>
  <LastName>Price</LastName>
  <ImagePath>5D03A73D-636A-2AD8-A02E-7BD7096C12A4</ImagePath>
  <flightno>GS1234</flightno>
 </User>
</UserImagePaths>

then im doing var userlist:XMLList = userXML.child("user").(flightNoArray.indexOf(child("flightno").text().toString()) >= 0);

but unable to parse error?

Comment: Its the indexof thats not working. The array is GS1234,TD1234 but when i do trace(flightNoArray.indexOf("GS1234")); its -1

Comment: Hmm. But that actually should work. :) Does my example work for you now as is? How do you collect that `flightNoArray`? Do you really have strings there or is it a result of some E4X query?

Comment: When you use indexOf you need to do it like trace(flightNoArray[0].indexOf("GS1234")); so you have to specify an array index. I need to filter my xml to only show the users whos flights exist in the user xml

Comment: I wanted to avoid a loop as there may be many more user records to come :(

Comment: How do you populate `flightNoArray` and what do you store there actually?

Comment: var flightNoArray: Array = [];

  for each(var num: XML in departingXML.flight) {
   flightNoArray.push(num.number);

  }
  trace(flightNoArray);

Which traces GS1234,TD1234 as expected. When using indexOf you have to specify the index.

Comment: Then with them flight numbers i want to select the users from the xml that have any of the numbers in the array, in there <flightno></flightno>

Comment: No, this is not what causes problems. What you have in `flightNoArray` are *not* strings, they are XMLLists most likely. It's just that `trace()` does toString() for you, and you don't suspect anything. )

Comment: If you give me `departingXML` structure sample, we will solve this at last.

Comment: <Flights>
    <flight>
  <number>GS1234</number>
  <date>10/11/2015</date>
  <time>1440</time>
 </flight>
  <flight>
  <number>TD1234</number>
  <date>10/11/2015</date>
  <time>1450</time>
 </flight>
</flights>

Comment: Ok, I figured it out and I was right about the `flightNoArray`. I'll update the answer in a minute. And you should definitely take a look at the reference link I posted.

Comment: Ready. The first block of code shows the answer to your question. The second big block of code explains why it was not previously working.

Comment: Thanks very much that's a great answer.

Comment: I was sure that would work fine since you traced the answer but its not working for me :S. The array is now an real array like you said but i get Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.on the  

var list:XMLList = userXML.User.(flightNoArray.indexOf(flightno.toString()) >= 0);

Comment: That must be a completely different problem. I guess some variables got messed-up when you copied. Can you provide a complete example of what you came up with? Just like I did in my answer. You may paste it on dpaste.com or the like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94825/discussion-between-nox-noctis-and-gaz-smith).

Comment: Yeah just a problem with the data, ill stop bothering you now! haha

Comment: Damn i was hoping i removed the link before you saw it xD